# Keep NodeJS connection object in shared database/memory

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm running Debian 8 with NodeJS 6, and are playing around with the IBM Watson IoT platform: https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-nodejs

I've created a gateway in IBM, and are able to connect and publish data to it with the following code:

```
var gatewayClient = new iotf.IotfGateway(config);

gatewayClient.connect();

gatewayClient.on('connect', function(){
    gatewayClient.publishGatewayEvent("status","json",'{"d" : { "cpu" : 60, "mem" : 50 }}');

});
```

The config contains unique information regarding my unique gateway.

My challenge is now, that I would like to be able to reuse this `gatewayClient` in other NodeJS instances. So I'm thinking of something like the following (pseudo-code):

```
var gatewayClient = new iotf.IotfGateway(config);
gatewayClient.connect();

sharedDatabase-perhaps-Redis[unique-gatewayClient-ID].push(gatewayClient);
```

And then in any NodeJS on the same server I can call:

```
sharedDatabase-perhaps-Redis[unique-gatewayClient-ID].publishGatewayEvent("status","json",'{"d" : { "cpu" : 60, "mem" : 50 }}');
```

I hope it make sense, but I'm a bit confused if it's archivable and how, and if Redis could be a solution or other database-kind-of-thing.

The entire idea is to be able to keep the connection alive/persistant and have clients from different NodeJS instances push data via that one, without creating new connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Network connections are not serializable and cannot easily be shared across processes.</s>

Instead, you should consider creating a single "master" process that maintains the connection with the IBM backend, and the clients will communicate with this master instead of with IBM directly (for IoT purposes, a common method of communication is using [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/)).

Also, what stops you from running the code that will be running in those separate Node.js processes in one single process? That would solve the problem too, as each piece of could would be able to use the connection directly.

From what I understand, you already have a single server process that accepts client messages and should relay those messages to the IBM backend. For each unique client, you want to create a new connection to the backend, or re-use a previously created connection.

You could use something like this (error handling withheld for brevity):

```
// Function to get the connection for a particular client id,
// or, if one doesn't exist yet, create a new one.

let clients = {};
function connectionForClient(uniqueGatewayClientID) {
  // Check if we already have a connection for this client.
  if (! clients[uniqueGatewayClientID])

    // No, create a new one, represented by a promise.
    clients[uniqueGatewayClientID] = new Promise(function(resolve) {
      let client = new iotf.IotfGateway(config);

      client.connect();

      client.on('connect', function() {
        resolve(client);
      });
    });

  }
  return clients[uniqueGatewayClientID];
}
```

To use:

```
connectionForClient(uniqueGatewayClientID).then(function(client) {
  client.publishGatewayEvent("status","json",'{"d" : { "cpu" : 60, "mem" : 50 }}');
});
```

Comment: I have my devices post json data to my NodeJS app which uses Express to listen on port 80. This data should be posted to IBM via the gateway connection, which might or might not be established. If it's established it should be used, if it't not it should be established so others can reuse that in the future.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean now: you need to create a new connection for each unique client. Let me think about that for a moment.

Comment: Ok, I think I've made a proof now where I simply make an Array outside my Express where I store IBM gatewayClients. And then check for isConnected when receiving a HTTP POST. This seems to due the trick, but scaling across servers (in the future) might be difficult...

Comment: @MichaelNielsen see my edit, which is similar to your solution. However, it's going to be very difficult to make this scalable, because like I said, you can't share connections between processes. You'd have to use something like sharding, where each server process would handle a particular subset of clients, based on their ID.

Comment: Ok, make sense. Thank you.